# checkbox slow to check

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using checkboxes to show or hide columns in jqGrid, and since I have many, many rows, each with many values in their cells, it takes a long time for the checkbox to finish checking when I check it.

I want the checkbox to check immediately and THEN do the time-consuming jqGrid operations. For example,

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
    // First render/unrender the checkmark    
    // Next do some very time-consuming jqGrid operations
}
```

How can I achieve this? As things stand, it's doing the jqGrid calls first, and only checking the checkox at the very end. It takes a full TWO seconds to check the checkbox!

Comment: Could you explain more exactly which checkboxes you mean? Is it checkboxes of [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) or you use some other custom interface where you just call `showCol` or `hideCol`?

Comment: Hi Oleg. I use a custom interface where I call showCol and hideCol. The problem occurs even when I use showCol on a single colName. I'm using jqGrid 4.4.1 so it has your cells[i] css optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the time-consuming code inside a timeout:

```
// immediate stuff here
setTimeout(function() {
   // time-consuming stuff here
},1);
```

Ideally, you'd want to put that time-consuming stuff in a Web Worker so as not to freeze up the UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can do optimizations in your page and script.

1. **Put your scripts before the end of `<body>` tag.**
2. **Use tools to improve performance :** The best tool I can recommend for this is [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/), it's a profiler for IE (typically the slowest in JS performance, so actually a good test environment for starting optimization).
   It'll give you a full breakdown, show you repeated method calls, the call tree and where your CPU cycles are going.  [Check out their tutorials on usage/features](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/learn/Default.aspx) to get started.
3. **[Improving jQuery Performance with Large Data Sets](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/5-easy-tips-on-how-to-improve-code.html)** topics include :

> 1. Use JavaScript native for() loop instead of jQuery's $.each() helper
>    function.
> 2. Do NOT append an element to the DOM in your loop.
> 3. If you have a lot of elements to be inserted into the DOM, surround them
>    with a parent element for better
>    performance.
> 4. Don't use string concatenation, instead use array's join() method for
>    a very    long strings.
> 5. Use setTimeout() function for your long list looping and concatenation
>    functions.
> 6. **Minify your scripts**

Hopefully these will be enough to get better performance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can render/un-render the checkmark in one `.click()` function then do your jqGrid operations in another `.click()`. i.e.

```
$('#selector').click(
    function(){//rendering stuff}
).click(
    function(){//computational stuff}
);
```

Comment: But how? I've spent all day trying to figure this out.

Comment: I believe that is correct although the 2nd `.click` might need to be a `.done`